# Multicast dns registers hostname based on IP address

Tags: wi-fi, ssh, dns

I would like to use avahi/zeroconf to do ssh logins to devices which are connected to the local network by wifi. Since I do not have control over the wifi routers I cannot assign fixed IP-addresses to the devices. Therefor I set up a multicast dns server (on my android phone) which registers the device. Now I see the device using an avahi-browser on my ubuntu notebook. However the hostname is assigned based on the IP-address, which I cannot know in advance. `avahi-discover` displays:

```
Service Type: _udisks-ssh._tcp
Service Name: samsungtablet
Domain Name: local
Interface: wlan0 IPv4
Address: 10-0-0-101.local/10.0.0.101:22
TXT Data: empty
```

I would like to be able to do
`ssh user@samsungtablet.local`
or something like this in order to log in. It works now with 
`ssh user@10-0-0-101.local`
but I cannot know this hostname in advance.

In contrast my Ubuntu notebook appears as

```
Service Type: _udisks-ssh._tcp
Service Name: einstein
Domain Name: local
Interface: wlan0 IPv4
Address: einstein.local/10.0.0.106:22
TXT Data: empty
```

Here `ssh user@einstein.local` will work.

Note that the hostname on the samsungtablet is set to `samsungtablet` using `net.hostname`. The multicast dns server I set up on the tablet contained in "servers ultimate" and the name there is set to `samsungtablet` as well.

Note that I am aware that `SSHelper` supports multicast dns as well, however I would prefere a solution where I can choose to keep my ssh-server.